# Создание exe посредством php

Tags: php, компиляция, exe

Есть сайт, там при вводе опеределеных данных скрипт формирует exe файл(написанный либо на c++ либо на delphi), который можно скачать и данные введенные ранее отображаются в этом файле.
Вопрос - куда копать чтобы сделать подобное?
P.S. По гуглил, ничего путного не нашел, возможно плохо искал.
UPD: Нашел на тостере подобный вопрос, но не понял решения https://toster.ru/q/51128

Comment: Нет, интересно как реализовать такую вещь

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чаще всего это делают записывая "полезную нагрузку" в оверлей.

Пишете на том же С++ приложение, которое при запуске открывает свой собственный exe-файл, находит конец последней секции, и читает оттуда необходимые для отображения данные. Ну и потом в своём веб-приложении просто отдаёте этот файл, на лету приклеивая в конец нужные данные:

```php
// открываем файл
$file = new SplFileObject('app.exe', 'rb');

// посылаем заголовки - тип содержимого и предлагаемое имя для его сохранения
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $file->getBasename());

// отправляем всё содержимое файла в браузер, и освобождаем файловый объект
$file->fpassthru();
$file = null;

// формируем и отправляем оверлей - например, ассоциативный масив в JSON
$overlay = array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'baz' => 'qux',
    'waldo' => 'fred'
);
echo json_encode($overlay);
```

Comment: А по подробнее? Как "приклеить" в конец данные?

Comment: @edvardpotter, дописал в ответ. Хоть и не уверен в работоспособности - PHP под рукой нет

Comment: А как потом использовать этот массив в c++? Вроде примерно понял, но все равно большая часть остается непонятной...

Comment: Протестил ваш код, все работает отлично - данные записываются в конце файла, осталось только понять как использовать их. Хотя наверное придется создать отдельный вопрос.

Comment: а как можно зашифровать эти данные,чтобы их могла видеть только программа?

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут вроде как раз ваша тема рассматривается http://habrahabr.ru/post/19705/

Comment: В корне не то, приложение не должно быть на php, php должен лишь передавать в него определенные данные как я уже писал выше.